# Ionic - this.navCtrl.push not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, navigation, handler

I have a very simple situation with this HTML:

```
<!--
  Generated template for the FormulasPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Formulas</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>
    <div class="formula" *ngFor="let j of items ; let i = index" id='{{i}}' (tap)="loadFolder(j.color)" no-lines no-padding>
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <img src="{{j.url}}">
                <div class="formulabar" #formulabar>{{j.color}}</div>
            </ion-col>
         </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

The relevant part is the `(tap)` handler on `div.formula`. This is the code that relates to that:

```
loadFolder(color) {
    console.log("load folder");
    console.log(color);
    this.navCtrl.push(FormulaPage);
}
```

The console message happens - `"load folder"`, but the page doesn't change.

Comment: Is formulapage declared on app.module.ts declarations and entryComponents?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because of something that was on the `FormulaPage` (I can't remember what exactly) - it did not have to do with the code on the page above. If you have this problem, look to the page you are pushing.